# R - run function to compute a new column form an existing one across each table in a list of tables

Tags: r

With a list of tables is it possible to generate a new column in each table, based on running a function across an existing column in each table.

Setup:

```
# dummy data
  df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c(1,2,3),  X2 = c(1,1,1))
  df2 <- data.frame(X1 = c(5,6,7),  X2 = c(0,0,0))
  df3 <- data.frame(X1 = c(8,9,10), X2 = c(1,0,1))

# dummy list
  list_01<-list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Is it possible then to create a column X3 from running a function across each instance of X2.

Expected output:

```
list_02[[3]]
       X1  X2  X3
    1  8   1   Yes
    2  9   0   No
    3  10  1   Yes
```

I attempted to nest the function in a cbind but this didn't work.

```
# lapply a function
  list_02<-lapply(list_01, function(x) 
             cbind(x, X3 = ( 
                      if( x$X2 > 0 ) {
                       "Yes"
                      } else if (x$X2 == 0) {
                       "No"
                      } else {
                       "error - check column X2 for numeric"
                      })))
```

This generates the following warning for me:

> Warning messages: In if (x$X2 > 0) { :   the condition has length >
> 1 and only the first element will be used

Which I don't understand, but think maybe means I'm not using lapply correctly to deal with the dimensions of the data, do I need to nest an apply within the lapply? Thanks for any help or ideas.

Comment: You're hitting a vector (`x$X2`) with a scalar condition `if(x$X2 > 0){...}`, which defaults to taking only the first element (here `TRUE`) from the vector (here `TRUE  FALSE  TRUE)`) produced by `x$X2 > 0`. Hence the warning: _"Warning messages: In if (x$X2 > 0) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"_. If you want a vectorized conditional in your `function(x){...}`, then use `dplyr::case_when()`. Better yet, leverage `library(dplyr)` to make things cleaner: `function(x){x %>% mutate(X3 = case_when(X2 > 0 ~ "Yes", X2 == 0 ~ "No", TRUE ~ "error..."))}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
lapply(list_01, function(x) setDT(x)[, X3 := ifelse(X2 == 1, "yes", "no")])

# [[1]]
#    X1 X2  X3
# 1:  1  1 yes
# 2:  2  1 yes
# 3:  3  1 yes
# 
# [[2]]
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1:  5  0 no
# 2:  6  0 no
# 3:  7  0 no
# 
# [[3]]
#    X1 X2  X3
# 1:  8  1 yes
# 2:  9  0  no
# 3: 10  1 yes
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `map()` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

list_01 %>%
  map( ~ .x %>%
         mutate(X3 = if_else(X2 > 0, "yes", "no")))

#> [[1]]
#>   X1 X2  X3
#> 1  1  1 yes
#> 2  2  1 yes
#> 3  3  1 yes

#> [[2]]
#>   X1 X2 X3
#> 1  5  0 no
#> 2  6  0 no
#> 3  7  0 no

#> [[3]]
#>   X1 X2  X3
#> 1  8  1 yes
#> 2  9  0  no
#> 3 10  1 yes
```

Answer (score 1):

`if` does not work on vectors. When you exchange the `if` with `ifelse` it might give the expected result.

```
list_02 <- lapply(list_01, function(x)
    cbind(x, X3 =
           ifelse(x$X2 > 0, "Yes",
                  ifelse(x$X2 == 0, "No", "error - check column X2 for numeric")
                  )
          )
    )

list_02
#[[1]]
#  X1 X2  X3
#1  1  1 Yes
#2  2  1 Yes
#3  3  1 Yes
#
#[[2]]
#  X1 X2 X3
#1  5  0 No
#2  6  0 No
#3  7  0 No
#
#[[3]]
#  X1 X2  X3
#1  8  1 Yes
#2  9  0  No
#3 10  1 Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

BaseR way

- as.logical() for number greater than 0 returns True and for 0 it returns false
- adding one above to above results will turn False to 1 and True to 2
- use these values as indexing for another vector `c('No', 'Yes')` and you'll get your desired results without using if/ifelse

```r
# dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = c(1,2,3),  X2 = c(1,1,1))
df2 <- data.frame(X1 = c(5,6,7),  X2 = c(0,0,0))
df3 <- data.frame(X1 = c(8,9,10), X2 = c(1,0,1))

# dummy list
list_01<-list(df1, df2, df3)

lapply(list_01, \(df) transform(df, X3 = c('No', 'Yes')[1 + as.logical(X2)]))
#> [[1]]
#>   X1 X2  X3
#> 1  1  1 Yes
#> 2  2  1 Yes
#> 3  3  1 Yes
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   X1 X2 X3
#> 1  5  0 No
#> 2  6  0 No
#> 3  7  0 No
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   X1 X2  X3
#> 1  8  1 Yes
#> 2  9  0  No
#> 3 10  1 Yes
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>